# How can I make my Applescript 'do' a script in my custom window?

Tags: bash, firefox-addon, applescript

I'm working on writing an Applescript that gets my Terminal ready for me to make Firefox add-ons.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "cd Public/addon-sdk-1.0"
    do script "source bin/activate"
    do script "clear"
end tell
```

When I run this script, my custom Terminal opens along with a regular Terminal window; and the bash script is ran in the regular window.. So, I'm trying to find out how to make the Applescript only open my custom Terminal, and execute the bash script in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your problem is to not use `do script` but to send keystrokes to your current terminal window with either `keystroke` or `key code`. Here's a script I use to do something similar. I just call this from the terminal with `osascript myscript.scpt` or launch it directly (I use [LaunchBar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html) for invoking applescripts) and it opens a new terminal tab (if the terminal is already open), gives it a custom name and then runs whatever commands I feed it. You could modify this to skip creating a new tab and just run in the current terminal window.  I only use this approach when I have to do more than just run some standard terminal commands (such as send keys to an interactive python session), otherwise I just create a bash script.

```
global ENTER_, ESC_
set ENTER_ to 52 
set ESC_ to 53 

on run_commands(commands, pause)
    tell application "System Events"
        repeat with cmd in commands
            keystroke cmd
            key code ENTER_
            delay pause
        end repeat
    end tell
end run_commands

on new_terminal_tab(tab_name)
    activate application "Terminal"
    delay 0.5 
    tell application "System Events"
        # create new tab
        keystroke "t" using {command down}
        delay 0.5 
        # give it a name
        keystroke "I" using {shift down, command down}
        keystroke tab_name 
        delay 0.5
        key code ESC_ # escape 
    end tell
end new_terminal_tab

new_terminal_tab("addon-sdk-work")
run_commands( { "cd /Users/username/Documents/dev/projname",¬ 
        ". env/bin/activate", ¬
        "clear"}, 0.5)
```

Comment: Oh wow, that's pretty cool! (I can tell I need to learn more about Applescript). But thank you, I believe this is what I was looking for.